# A sci fi movie aired on Discovery where robots are sent to an exoplanet

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching a movie or an episode on the Discovery Channel somewhere between 2008 to 2012.

Humans sent a few robots to an exoplanet. This exoplanet had dinosaur-like animals and a very greenish atmosphere. There were three robots/vehicles sent from which the first crashed and the other two made it by gathering its entry data. The robots/vehicles floated by expanding their structure or something (or my brain made this up.)

I remember one of the creatures was a sort of a sleeping mountain with four thin long legs and sort of thin from the sides and covered in moss.

I watched the show in Hindi so have no recollection of the narrator.

Comment: If it was Discovery, it's unlikely to be a movie. It's far more likely to be a faux documentary

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the 'docufiction' show [*Alien Planet*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Planet).

> Alien Planet is a 2005 docufiction TV special created for the Discovery Channel.
>
> ...
>
> Alien Planet starts out with an interstellar spacecraft named Von Braun, leaving Earth's orbit. Traveling at 20% the speed of light (37,000 miles/s), it reaches Darwin IV, a planet 6.5 light-years away, in 42 years. Upon reaching orbit, it deploys the Darwin Reconnaissance Orbiter, which looks for potential landing sites for the probes. The first probe, Balboa, explodes along with its lifting body transport during entry, because one of its wings failed to unfold. Two backup probes, Leonardo da Vinci (nicknamed Leo) and Isaac Newton (nicknamed Ike), successfully land on the planet, and learn much about its bizarre indigenous lifeforms, including an apparently sapient species.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for thank you so much!